# Uploading images via FTP and preventing errors when loading php script with the pictures

Tags: php, image, server, ftp

I am uploading images via FTP to a folder on my server using a FTP client. I am using a php script to display all the images in that folder. However when a file is being uploaded and the page is accessed at the same time, the image being uploaded gets corrupted.

Here is my pHp script

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>


<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
 {
   $image = $files[$i];
   $supported_file = array(
           'gif',
           'jpg',
           'jpeg',
           'png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
       echo basename($image)."<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";
        echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
       } else {
           continue;
       }
     }
  ?>
  </body>
```

Comment: You could upload them with a different file extension (one that you're not using to look for when displaying them, eg: .wait) and then after upload is complete rename it to whatever image file extension it should be.

Comment: Not really [on-topic question here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Anyway, see https://superuser.com/q/878570/213663

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you upload the files in a different directory first, and after that move the files to "images" directory.
You can make a php script that do that when executed

Comment: I have read about that. The problem is how to know if the file has been completely uploaded. Actually the application for which I'm developing it, this needs to be as closest to real-time.